# Binding project type for Monomac

Tags: monodevelop, monomac, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

In **Xamarin Studio** there is an **iOS Binding project type**. It can be used to create bindings to Objective-C libraries and frameworks. It internally uses btouch tool (see Xamarin.ObjcBinding.CSharp.targets reference in your project file). So on each build Xamarin Studio runs btouch and creates needed assembly.

There are no such things for Monomac (Xamarin.Mac) at the moment. So it's really not so easy to manage Monomac bindings. We should manually run bmac tool (btouch equivalent for Monomac).

What's your approach to solve this problem? Has anybody successfully automated Monomac binding project build process in a way it works for Monotouch?

Comment: Have you tried to use post build scripts?

Comment: Not yet. Hoped that someone already got the working solution.

Comment: Would it be an acceptable solution for you?